# Where to edit footer color in Wordpress Flash theme?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The purpose is to change the colour of the text in the footer of my Wordpress site. At the footer you can see the color of the text is black and not visible.

Wondering where do you insert the code below to edit in CSS the FLASH themes to change the text color of the footer?

Can't seem to post image, so link of image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gA6s.png)

On my [Computer Repairs](https://www.chatswoodcomputer.com.au/) website, I've tried addinto into style.css, but nothing seems to change

```
.site-footer {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Was expect the text to be white, but it is still showing up as dark color when adding the code above. Perhaps I'm adding in the wrong section

Answer (score 1):

Try to add !important to the end of CSS value to overwrite original styles.
And you can do it through the admin interface by clicking "Customize" and then "Additional CSS".

Comment: Wow, it works, thanks

.site-footer {
    color: #fff !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

```css
Add below css code into your current active child theme’s style.css file or you can add additional css option in theme customizer.

.site-footer {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.site-footer a {
  color: #000;
}
Hope this will helps you.

Thanks.
```

[Virtual Credit Card](https://techpanga.com/top-virtual-credit-card/)